# Open app without Launcher icon with package Manager and Broadcast

Tags: java, android, icons, broadcast, launcher

I want open a app without Launcher icon with Package Manager and Broadcast. But After me make a package Manager  and after I builded app my app is crashed. Plz help me.
My Main activity code:

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.*;

import android.os.*;

import android.view.*;

import android.view.View.*;

import android.widget.*;

import android.content.*;

import android.content.res.*;

import android.graphics.*;

import android.graphics.drawable.*;

import android.media.*;

import android.net.*;

import android.text.*;

import android.text.style.*;

import android.util.*;

import android.webkit.*;

import android.animation.*;

import android.view.animation.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.util.regex.*;

import java.text.*;

import org.json.*;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.view.View;

import android.app.Fragment;

import android.app.FragmentManager;

import android.app.DialogFragment;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private LinearLayout linear1;


private LinearLayout linear2;


private TextView textview2;


private TextView textview3;





private Intent xnnzm = new Intent();


private Intent content = new Intent();


private Intent context = new Intent();

private PackageManager pm   = new PackageManager();





@Override


protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    initialize(_savedInstanceState);


    initializeLogic();


}





private void initialize(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {


    linear1 = findViewById(R.id.linear1);


    linear2 = findViewById(R.id.linear2);


    textview2 = findViewById(R.id.textview2);


    textview3 = findViewById(R.id.textview3);


    


    linear2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override


        public void onClick(View _view) {


            xnnzm.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);


            startActivity(xnnzm);


        }


    });


}





private void initializeLogic() {


}








@Deprecated


public void showMessage(String _s) {


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), _s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}





@Deprecated


public int getLocationX(View _v) {


    int _location[] = new int[2];


    _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);


    return _location[0];


}





@Deprecated


public int getLocationY(View _v) {


    int _location[] = new int[2];


    _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);


    return _location[1];


}





@Deprecated


public int getRandom(int _min, int _max) {


    Random random = new Random();


    return random.nextInt(_max - _min + 1) + _min;


}





@Deprecated


public ArrayList<Double> getCheckedItemPositionsToArray(ListView _list) {


    ArrayList<Double> _result = new ArrayList<Double>();


    SparseBooleanArray _arr = _list.getCheckedItemPositions();


    for (int _iIdx = 0; _iIdx < _arr.size(); _iIdx++) {


        if (_arr.valueAt(_iIdx))


        _result.add((double)_arr.keyAt(_iIdx));


    }


    return _result;


}





@Deprecated


public float getDip(int _input) {


    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, _input, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


}





@Deprecated


public int getDisplayWidthPixels() {


    return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;


}





@Deprecated


public int getDisplayHeightPixels() {


    return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;


}
```

}
`

I try to made a Package Manager and Broadcast for open App without Launcher icon

Comment: please remove all the imports and all the double carriage returns. This will help to make the code you posted more readable. thanks!

Comment: Please only post the relevant code parts. At the moment I see a lot of common code but nothing that matches your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
private PackageManager pm   = new PackageManager();
```

You cannot create an instance of `PackageManager` that way. Instead, get a `PackageManager` instance by calling `getPackageManager()` on your `Activity`, sometime after the `super.onCreate()` call in `onCreate()`.

---

In the future, when your app crashes, please [use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html). If you do not understand the stack trace, include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the bureport information, which will allow for further detailed analysis.